# Regex to remove dollar symbol and trailing zeros for a price input

Tags: java, regex

I want to remove the trailing zeros after the period and `$` symbol from a price input. For example,

```
$100    -> 100
$10.000  -> 10
$10.0100 -> 10.01 
$10.1234 -> 10.1234
```

I have the following regex, however, it doesn't remove the `$` nor the period `.` sign: `[.0]+$`. Also, it removes all zeros.

Comment: What about the `.0010`? `0.001` or `.001`? What about just removing `$` with `.replace("$","")` and then converting a String to a float?

Comment: Consider: rather than trying to remove, capture and keep what you want. Use a matcher with groups.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Hm good quesiton , didn't even consider that. But for those values it should remain the same.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/vGfWDf/1

Comment: @KevinO It has to be a regex. The way my application is built , we have a gui where we place a regex inside which formats the value so that is why I need a regex .

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Omg , i didn't even know about that site. Thanks! Very useful. But i noticed it replaces 100 with 1 which I only need it to remove the trailing zeros.

Comment: Ok, try [`.replaceAll("^\\$|(?:(\\.[0-9]*[1-9])|\\.)0+$", "$1")`](https://regex101.com/r/vGfWDf/2)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Worked great. Thanks so much! Can you please make your regex as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
String result = s.replaceAll("^\\$|(?:(\\.[0-9]*[1-9])|\\.)0+$", "$1");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vGfWDf/2).

**Details**

- `^\\$` - a `$` char at the start of the string
- `|` - or
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group matching either of the 2 alternatives:

  - `(\\.[0-9]*[1-9])` - Capturing group 1 (later referred to with the `$1` placeholder): a `.` followed with 0+ digits followed with a digit other than `0`
  - `|` - or
  - `\\.` - a dot
- `)` - end of the non-capturing group
- `0+` - 1+ zeros
- `$` - end of string.